# construct an unknown url from known information

Tags: python, url

I'm trying to create a python script... basically...

I have a url to some site

```
url = "http://www.somesite.com/foo/bar/"
```

Files on server:

```
1-123j.jpg
2-123.jpg
3-123d.jpg
4-1594ss.jpg
...
...
45000-457li.jpg
```

I know the beginning of the filename (a number) and the file extension (.jpg), but there is a part of the name that is unknown(some random string that I don't know)...

How do I construct a url to "2-123.jpg" if I don't know the 123 part of the name?

What I know...

```
correctURL = "http://www.somesite.com/foo/bar/2-*****.jpg"
```

the correct url would be:

```
"http://www.somesite.com/foo/bar/2-123.jpg"
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: How do you expect to get the middle part of the name, if you don't know it?

Comment: outside of brute force I'm not sure how you'd do this unless you can look at the contents of `http://www.somesite.com/foo/bar`

Comment: A head scratcher... I know...

Comment: Do you have any information on the structure of the random string you have to work with?  Will it always be within certain length parameters?  Brute-forcing all 5 character strings is less bad than brute-forcing all strings.

Comment: Are you looking for help for brute-forcing, or actually asking if there is some technical magic whereby we can divine a valid, existing filename somehow?

Comment: By no means Im trying to brute-force the server... that is why im asking... bruteforcing the answer in no fun... in fact the only server transaction that I would like is just a clickable link...

Comment: I do have access to the server and I do have access to the "bar"folder  i can see the files in that folder... thousands of files that only share two things in common... filetype and the beginning of the name, that is a consecutive number... so to a point, the url would be unique.... So I guess the question should be...is there something like a wildcard that could be use in a URL?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from mentioning that it is quite hard to guess random urls, I'll go ahead and post an answer with some assumptions that might lead to a valid solution. The disclaimer here is that I don't know what your possibilities are with regard to server access and such, and hence will make several assumptions on filename formats or directory contents and the like. If you have no server access, then your solution doesn't really have a real answer to it, I guess.

So, here goes. First, get a list of filenames on the server:

```
import os
with open('filenames.txt') as f:
    files = os.listdir('.') # Assuming you are in the correct dir
    f.write('\n'.join(files))
```

This gives you all available files on the server. Generate this as often as you want, automate it, preferably with copying it to your web server so that you are always up to date.

Then, on your web server, do something like this:

```
files = open('filenames.txt').read().split('\n')
d = {}
for f in files:
    s = f.split('-', 1)
    d[s[0]] = s[-1]
```

Your dictionary now contains the key/value pairs needed to construct the correct filename. You can do this periodically, storing the result somewhere for faster access, or just run it whenever you need to construct an url.

The final step is to construct the url, like so:

```
n = 2 # The number you got somewhere
fmt = 'http://www.somesite.com/foo/bar/{}-{}'
url = fmt.format(n, d[n])
```

Comment: You should do `f.split("-",1)` to ensure you only split at the first dash.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get this done, use `wget`:

```
wget -r -|1 --no-parent -A.jpg http://www.somesie.com/foo/bar/
```

In Python, it would be a cumbersome exercise.